# When button click, the visibility of a button should be collapsed in another page - UWP

Tags: xml, xaml, button, uwp, navigation

I am making a uwp app, and in the settings page, there is a left navigation view, and when I go to the appearance section, and click on a button, the button in another page (MainPage) should be collapsed, is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When button click, the visibility of a button should be collapsed in another page - UWP

For this scenario, you could use mvvmlight Messenger to approach. And if the other page  and send page are not in the same window. you need set other page  `NavigationCacheMode="Required"` in the xaml.

**the page that you want to hide the button**

```
public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent(); 
     Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(this,(s) =>
     {
         if (s)
         {
             MyBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         }
        
     });

 }
```

**the page that send the command to above page**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true);
 }
```

Comment: yes done, sry for the late reply!